# virt-manager - reduce guest machine screen height

Tags: virt-install

I am running my `Centos7` guest on a `Ubuntu 14.04` host machine. On bringing up the guest machine, the guest machine's screen height is more than the host machine's screen size. So, scroll bars appear on right side of `virt-manager` screen. But, in the command prompt, navigation using the scroll bar to see the top/bottom of the screen is difficult for me.

How can i reduce the guest machine's screen height and make it less than or equal to the host machine's height?

Comment: The default guest resolution is 1024x768. Have you got a very small monitor?

Comment: yes. It is a dell laptop whose monitor is possibly 20 to 25% lesser than normal monitors. i couldn't get the exact dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You had to lower the virtualized display resolution - ie the resolution at which your virtual machine runs. Set it to a lower value (for example, 800x600).

Comment: `virt-manager` doesn't have any options related to display resolution. all i see on the left side is, `Display VNC`, `Video Cirrus`, `Tablet`. At least these sub-menus don't have this option.